# NullPointerException when get element from an ArrayList

Tags: java

I just want to get the first few elements from a list. But when I do this, there's a null pointer at line

```
returnList.add(returnList1.get(i))
```

I tested the `returnList1`. It has values.

```
ArrayList<someObject> returnList1 = new ArrayList<someObject>();
ArrayList<someObject> returnList = new ArrayList<someObject>();
returnList1=bunruiSummaryService.getFromDB(param);
int j = 10;
if(returnList1.size() < j){
    j = returnList1.size();
}
for(int i = 0; i<j; i++){
    returnList.add(returnList1.get(i));
}
```

Comment: `returnList1` might be null. Are you sure your service returns a non-empty list?

Comment: You haven't shown us where you have initialized `returnList` Also returnList1 initialization doesn't make any sense since you assign the value return by function. You should add values to list rather than changing the reference

Comment: 2 cases: 1. You forgot to initialize `returnList`. 2. `bunruiSummaryService.getFromDB(param)` returns `null`. (BTW, if you are going to rewrite `returnList1` immediately why not just do: `ArrayList<someObject> returnList1 = bunruiSummaryService.getFromDB(param);`?

Comment: Where are you initializing `returnlist`?

Comment: I haven't even seen that `returnList` and `returnList1` are two different lists! I would also recommend to rename them to make your code more readable.

Comment: But if returnList1 would be null, wouldn't the NullPointerException be thrown when he checks the size of returnList1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many problems with this little piece of code. Let me show you how I'd like to see it:

```
//somewhere else defined
private static final int MAX_SIZE_OF_SOME_LIST = 10; //instead of j=10, you simply have to know what the number 10 represents!

List<SomeObject> resultList = new ArrayList<someObject>();
List<SomeObject> returnList = bunruiSummaryService.getFromDB(param); //at this point, make sure to return an empty list instead of null
int maxSize = MAX_SIZE_OF_SOME_LIST;
if(returnList.size() < MAX_SIZE_OF_SOME_LIST){
    maxSize = returnList.size(); //if you ensured the returned list is not null, if the returned list is empty, you get 0 here
}
//even so
int maxSize = returnList.size() < MAX_SIZE_OF_SOME_LIST ? returnList.size() : MAX_SIZE_OF_SOME_LIST;

for(int i = 0; i<maxSize; i++){
    resultList.add(returnList.get(i));
}

//or you could use subList:
resultList.addAll(returnList.subList(0, maxSize));
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all,there are many loop holes in your code.

Coming to NPE,

Either   `returnList1=bunruiSummaryService.getFromDB(param);`  returning `null`

Possibility is  you are not intialised `returnList`

```
returnList.add(returnList1.get(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a null check before using it and handle accordingly:

```
ArrayList<someObject> returnList1 = new ArrayList<someObject>();
    returnList1=bunruiSummaryService.getFromDB(param);
    if(returnList1 == null) 
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR: List is null");  
        //handle as per your need
    }
```

You may also need to check how have you initialized your returnList. I think there is some problem there.

Comment: I wouldn't return a null in the first place. I'd rather return an empty list from the service.

Comment: I initialize returnList as globle varaible and of course, returnList1 have value

Comment: @LongVu Where have you initialized your returnList? Can you share that code? I think there is some problem there.

Comment: @LongVu Not sure whether the code you have shared is actually the code you are executing. Can you provide the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

You create the ArrayList for returnList1, then you overwrite it with the data from the database, but you don't create the ArrayList for returnList. You should replace:

```
ArrayList<someObject> returnList1 = new ArrayList<someObject>();
```

with

```
ArrayList<someObject> returnList = new ArrayList<someObject>();
```

Comment: And you don't have exceptions at the line if(returnList1.size() < j)? In that case neither returnList1 seems to be null, so the exception at the last line seems very strange.

Comment: I checked returnList1 is not null.